# Getting an exception raised by django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve

Tags: django

I am naive in Django. Trying out a few pieces of stuff here. I was working with static files and have got stuck here. Please help me out here.

I am very much confused about static_root and static_dirs. I am following an online tutorial where the static root has not been used and their project is working fine. If am trying that I facing lots of errors and exceptions.

Here is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse



def index(request):
    my_dict={'insert_me':"Hello I am from views.py"}
    return render(request,'first_app/index.html',context=my_dict)
```

Here is my projects urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from first_app import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^first_app/',include('first_app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Here is my apps url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from first_app import views
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'', views.index, name='index'),]
```

the index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles%} 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>DJ Page</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Hello this is index.html!</h1> 
        <img src="{% static 'images/dj.jpg'%}" alt='oh oh! did not show'> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

and here is my setting:

"""

```
Django settings for Twenty3rdMrach project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
#TEMPLATES_DIR=os.path.join(TEMPLATES_DIR,'first_app')
print(TEMPLATES_DIR)
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
print (STATIC_DIR   )



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'mz^^exko@!2czk35u$w-qr&v8u(46(fp7#u41ctabvwf=mz9m&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Twenty3rdMrach.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Twenty3rdMrach.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'udemy1',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'Ravi@go123',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_media/')
```

While hitting the url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/dj.jpg
```

am facing the below error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/dj.jpg
Raised by:  django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve
'images\dj.jpg' could not be found
```

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Can you share your template `index.html`?

Comment: @Aurélien here is my template index.html code:


{% load staticfiles%}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DJ Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello this is index.html!</h1>
<img src="{% static 'images/dj.jpg'%}" alt='oh oh! did not show'>
</body>
</html>

Comment: where is your `images` directory located?

Answer (score 1):

**STATICFILES_DIR** - Setting is to tell Django which directories to be scanned for static files.

**STATIC_ROOT** -  Setting is to tell Django where to put all the static files when `python manage.py collectstatic` command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the trailing slash in `STATICFILES_DIR` and `STATIC_ROOT`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_media')
```